# Image-Shaped Window in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, transparency, shapes

I want to have a WPF-Window that is shaped like an image. So basically I have an image that contains transparency and at the transparent places I just want to see through the window to my desktop. In the non-transparent places I want to see my image. Similar to what is done [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSWPFIrregularShapeWindow-4a12c25f), but in a way that is simple and understandable(in the example I linked there is LOTS of XAML and I don't understand a word).

Comment: If you expect to do anything in WPF you'd better start learning XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Much of the XAML you see in that example is stuff unrelated to just showing a window that only shows the image.  The rest of it is basically handling the minimize/maximize/close buttons.

To get you started, the below is all you really need to show a window that just has your image.  You can then go from here and add buttons and things as needed, using that example XAML from the article to lead you on.

```
<Window x:Class="CSWPFIrregularShapeWindow.PictureBasedWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="PictureBasedWindow" Height="300" Width="300" Background="Transparent" 
        WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="True" >    
    <Grid>
    <Image Height="250" Name="test" Source="/CSWPFIrregularShapeWindow;component/Images/transparentPic.png" 
        Stretch="Fill" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Will the app take focus when you click on a transparent part of the window?

Comment: @Peter I don't believe so, but I'm not positive.  I believe the transparent portion wont propagate the click routed event up the chain.  It should be easy enough to throw together a project with this setup and try it out.  I don't have time to right now, but feel free to chime in with the results if you do so.

Comment: Cool, show how you would get other controls on the window, perhaps?

Comment: @MaximV.Pavlov Add any other controls you want to show inside the Grid element below the Image element as they will overlay the image.